# How to handle a dependency with multiple other dependeccies in dagger?

Tags: android, dagger

I am currently introducing dagger into an android application. I am a bit worried with a design aspect and I am wondering whether there is a better way to handle it. Let us use the example provided [here](http://square.github.io/dagger/) to illustrate the question. Consider the following module;

```
@Module
class DripCoffeeModule {
  @Provides Heater provideHeater() {
    return new ElectricHeater();
  }

  @Provides Pump providePump(Thermosiphon pump) {
    return pump;
  }
}
```

Here, it is easy to see that the creation of a pump depends on a `Thermosiphon` and because of that, it is provided as an arg in the `providePump` method. likewise, if we wanted the `DripCoffeeModule` Module to be able to provide an object of type `C` whose dependencies where a `Heater` and a `Pump`, we'd have the following method:

```
@Provides
C provideC(Heater heater, Pump pump){
  C wantedC = applyMagic(heater, pump)
  return c
}
```

If the `provideC` method had 16 (or any large number of) dependencies, would it have 16 or more args? Is there no better way of handle such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case I'd argue your design of `C` is flawed. From the [IntelliJ IDEA Code Inspections List](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp):

> **Overly Coupled Class**
>   This inspection reports any instances of classes which are highly
>   coupled, i.e. that reference too many other classes. Classes with too
>   high a coupling can be very fragile, and should probably be broken up.

Thus, you don't want to have 16 dependencies for your `C` class, but you want ~2-3-4 dependencies for it, which in turn depend on a small number of  classes.

---

If you really want a lot of dependencies, you can annotate the constructor  with `@Inject`. Then the `@Provides C provideC(...)` method is not necessary:

```
public class C {

  @Inject
  public C(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, ...) { /* ... */ }

  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: 16 was an arbitrary number i just chose. I have a class which has five dependencies, but 5 args seem to be a bit much.